# How to use *args and self in Python constructor

Tags: python, args

I need a Python method to have access to self for instance variables and also be able to take any number of arguments.  I basically want a method foo that can be called via

```
foo(a, b, c)
```

or

```
foo()
```

In the class, I think the constructor would be

```
def foo(self, *args):
```

Is this correct?  Also, fyi, I am new to Python (if you can't tell).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does \*\* (double star/asterisk) and \* (star/asterisk) do for parameters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36901/what-does-double-star-asterisk-and-star-asterisk-do-for-parameters)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just have to add it after the `self` parameter:

```
class YourClass:
    def foo(self, *args):
        print(args)
    def bar(self, *args, **kwargs):
        print(args)
        print(kwargs)
    def baz(self, **kwargs):
        print(kwargs)
```

I have also added a method in which you also add `**kwargs`, and the case in which you add both `*args` and `**kwargs`.

#### Examples

```
>>> o = YourClass()
>>> o.foo()
()
>>> o.foo(1)
(1,)
>>> o.foo(1, 2)
(1, 2)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def foo(self, *args):
```

Yes, that is correct.

Answer (score 1):

You declared the method correctly. You can also use double asterisks to accept keyword arguments.
[Reference: Expressions](https://docs.python.org/3.6/reference/expressions.html?highlight=asterisk)

> A double asterisk ** denotes dictionary unpacking. Its operand must be a mapping. Each mapping item is added to the new dictionary. Later values replace values already set by earlier key/datum pairs and earlier dictionary unpackings.
>
> ....
>
> An asterisk * denotes iterable unpacking. Its operand must be an iterable. The iterable is expanded into a sequence of items, which are included in the new tuple, list, or set, at the site of the unpacking.

Args will be a tuple. To access the values you will have to iterate or use positional arguments, ie: args[0]